# How to stick title of scrollable content and when the content gets over title too should scroll and then happens with next scroll content

Tags: css, reactjs

I am working on ReactJS ,I have three Scrollable  content and I want to fix title for each section of the title
eg:- There are movies so I want to fix title Movie and all content should scroll then if the movies completes then the Title should too move with the scroll

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `position: sticky` and `top: 0` for your headers.

For multiple headers use `z-index` property to stack one over the other

```css
  * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family:sans-serif;

      }

      header {
        background-color: #7a7a7a;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family:sans-serif;

      }

      header {
        background-color: #7a7a7a;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header><h1>HEADING 1</h1></header>
    <article>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa libero
        assumenda fuga mollitia fugit minus aliquam in, quod perferendis sequi
        nulla, autem ipsum ullam cum, vel tempore dolorum obcaecati ut.
      </p>
   
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid
        veritatis repellendus ex, autem nulla mollitia ab repudiandae earum hic
        assumenda facilis? Nam perferendis iste nihil tempora iure animi at
        illum! Culpa aspernatur architecto eos minus aut adipisci odio
        voluptatibus dicta, labore nobis doloribus tempore quis enim minima
        laborum velit assumenda delectus libero consequatur vero commodi!
        Quaerat dolorem molestiae corrupti aut. Magni, aliquid ipsum, debitis
        placeat voluptatem eos nisi et esse dicta nam corrupti tempore cumque
        necessitatibus libero! Laudantium aliquid, facilis ut explicabo eligendi
        praesentium accusamus, dolorum iure, ab sit officia. Praesentium minus
        exercitationem nemo unde non corporis ipsum neque labore dolores commodi
        amet alias tempora odio aperiam in quia quo, quod mollitia repellat
        excepturi impedit! Ex rem suscipit temporibus quaerat. Perferendis
        beatae facilis quaerat illum ex, pariatur maiores ipsa in, iste ullam
        itaque excepturi consequatur. Excepturi nisi, consequuntur, esse saepe,
        exercitationem nihil blanditiis totam laboriosam explicabo quis
        inventore praesentium deserunt. Qui, impedit vitae, earum veritatis
        delectus est excepturi veniam commodi consequuntur temporibus quia at ad
        nisi eaque odio reiciendis reprehenderit consectetur exercitationem in
        perspiciatis tempore, culpa quisquam cumque dolor! Nulla! Distinctio
        voluptatum blanditiis molestias laudantium veritatis sint beatae?
        Explicabo accusantium at omnis qui cumque quas temporibus modi, porro
        perspiciatis totam ut dolores cupiditate ullam in deserunt dolore quasi.
        Officiis, eaque! Labore provident tempore sunt at. Pariatur amet eius
        odio, labore numquam, laboriosam magni ipsa porro deleniti quas ipsam
        quo vero. Aut reprehenderit perspiciatis culpa voluptas maiores placeat
        dolores, laborum aspernatur. Voluptatibus assumenda impedit vel in
        nostrum quas rem reprehenderit! Est expedita eligendi distinctio
        recusandae autem repellendus nam quia modi velit soluta laborum quisquam
        officia, quis fugit saepe. Magnam, similique quos. Sequi aliquid
        blanditiis itaque corrupti pariatur dolorem nemo debitis, veniam,
        voluptatem fugiat quis obcaecati qui assumenda molestiae, iusto tempore
        aperiam accusantium nostrum enim impedit alias minus! Numquam molestiae
        pariatur illum. Atque doloremque saepe voluptate, nisi rem aliquam iste
        architecto, dolorem recusandae consequatur suscipit laudantium mollitia
        libero incidunt, alias laborum? Quam nostrum quidem magni ab voluptas
        earum eum quo assumenda est? Deserunt impedit porro aut dolore
        necessitatibus possimus voluptate non libero error vel ab, nesciunt
        consequatur beatae minus ea doloribus assumenda cumque perferendis esse
        culpa. Quisquam aut distinctio qui molestias. Dolore. Quisquam corporis
        iusto ullam error molestiae delectus, doloremque saepe hic qui minus
        optio obcaecati sed repellendus. Voluptatibus ex perspiciatis veritatis
        ipsa quisquam? Ad id, tempore totam reiciendis voluptatem magnam porro.
        Deleniti minima, aliquid voluptatem voluptatibus officia possimus iste
        repellat accusantium neque laborum quisquam distinctio maiores ex
        quaerat, necessitatibus, suscipit natus nobis ducimus! Laboriosam
        deserunt odit odio delectus expedita enim ea? Sapiente, quisquam nobis,
        tenetur autem vitae accusamus praesentium nisi dolorem placeat culpa
        quia quaerat cupiditate quas, ab consequuntur optio amet hic et.
        Suscipit, molestias nulla? Tenetur deleniti fugit amet nemo! Quas
        praesentium ipsum harum deleniti nisi hic, at saepe eaque repellendus
        repudiandae neque perspiciatis a ipsa maxime commodi veniam iure
        nesciunt assumenda, perferendis placeat alias eligendi. Qui ea tempora
        eligendi. Totam adipisci iste nihil in sequi quas libero, corporis neque
        culpa voluptas quaerat temporibus consequatur, iure aliquam voluptate
        impedit repudiandae pariatur nam fuga alias! Fugit corporis magni quis
        ut dignissimos! Sunt, hic tenetur, autem assumenda quae rem facilis
        asperiores itaque omnis similique laborum eos dignissimos vel in alias,
        accusamus iste nesciunt reiciendis? Consequuntur enim, illum facilis
        similique nobis officia est. Laboriosam ducimus illum possimus,
        provident quis fugit blanditiis ex odit mollitia? Perspiciatis,
        sapiente, laudantium quas officia eaque tenetur, unde ab praesentium
        labore perferendis ullam expedita minima veniam voluptas itaque
        incidunt. Voluptatum ad, dolorem velit optio repudiandae quasi voluptate
        obcaecati enim architecto quam laboriosam vitae. Quod, inventore! Animi
        perferendis natus veniam vero, omnis porro doloribus fugit, sequi
        reprehenderit itaque, deserunt nemo!
        labore perferendis ullam expedita minima veniam voluptas itaque
        incidunt. Voluptatum ad, dolorem velit optio repudiandae quasi voluptate
        obcaecati enim architecto quam laboriosam vitae. Quod, inventore! Animi
        perferendis natus veniam vero, omnis porro doloribus fugit, sequi
        reprehenderit itaque, deserunt nemo!
      </p>
    </article>
    <header><h1>HEADING 2</h1></header>
    <article>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates
        fugiat rem omnis magnam impedit, veritatis expedita doloremque vel
        tempora architecto, eius deserunt voluptate doloribus saepe quos?
        Laboriosam iure nam odio? Molestiae iste, quasi delectus deleniti fuga
        ratione temporibus itaque ad ipsum tempora asperiores, eveniet corporis
        voluptates nemo explicabo. Ad perspiciatis autem, non quaerat saepe
        deserunt beatae vel esse neque nihil? Omnis ducimus placeat unde dolore
        repellendus asperiores animi impedit dolor repellat error inventore quia
        hic sint dignissimos laudantium modi fugiat explicabo, possimus
        perferendis ipsum cumque tempore quos mollitia! Illo, vel. Consequuntur,
        necessitatibus officiis dolores sit reprehenderit praesentium sint
        maxime dolore maiores distinctio eveniet aut ullam vitae, laboriosam nam
        quibusdam explicabo repudiandae possimus. Ipsum neque porro eum
        quibusdam corrupti reprehenderit est? Consectetur sequi sunt nam enim
        aperiam, labore commodi. Minima asperiores facere soluta, eius molestiae
        voluptas ea doloremque exercitationem laboriosam, veniam consectetur!
        Unde necessitatibus dolore facilis ut cum quis beatae tempora? Tenetur
        at adipisci optio delectus ab laudantium dolorem ipsa error, soluta,
        aperiam explicabo! Nulla cumque dolorum facere deleniti et accusamus
        quisquam reprehenderit voluptatibus assumenda perferendis doloribus
        fuga, quasi aliquid quas. Provident aliquid tempore modi labore! Quos
        fugiat unde placeat? Animi esse excepturi sunt illum, voluptate,
        deleniti obcaecati nam eius laboriosam natus expedita, atque voluptates
        soluta? Maxime obcaecati quae ullam ut. Perferendis, tempore! Repellat,
        cupiditate. Deleniti non expedita officiis exercitationem est aperiam
        odio error consequuntur, nam suscipit libero tempora, aliquid
        architecto, numquam quod? Ullam explicabo fuga possimus quas molestias
        earum nihil? Blanditiis cum accusantium fugit quae, expedita nam
        praesentium ullam ea minus suscipit dolores pariatur atque voluptates
        velit illum, esse culpa architecto. Dignissimos repudiandae recusandae
        ipsam, fugiat a laudantium sed fuga? Labore soluta explicabo quisquam,
        fuga voluptatum dolorem? Qui obcaecati amet consectetur vel, ea fugiat
        facilis? Quo cupiditate, hic, dolorem eius assumenda quisquam illo
        libero voluptates vel eum commodi. Blanditiis, amet? Veniam pariatur
        repudiandae totam consequuntur doloremque odit at quo officia, nulla
        debitis obcaecati in harum alias esse, libero eligendi. Quo explicabo
        iusto consequatur. Provident alias explicabo est recusandae architecto
        aliquid. Ea placeat possimus blanditiis, commodi exercitationem repellat
        earum perferendis vel nemo, fugit labore atque quisquam impedit, fugiat
        deserunt. Dolorem ipsam vero nostrum tenetur sapiente provident sequi
        praesentium hic, vel atque. Neque rem eos architecto! Ullam dolore,
        sequi a molestiae at modi earum ratione! Natus, enim saepe vero veniam
        deleniti laborum temporibus nostrum voluptatem ipsa eveniet vel! Quos
        illum ipsum laboriosam? Quibusdam aliquam autem officia sequi ratione in
        eius rerum numquam! Consequuntur corrupti, nisi deleniti aspernatur
        iure, blanditiis doloribus dicta ab sed, tempora omnis perferendis
        ratione quis nihil magnam dolorum nostrum! Nesciunt consectetur ipsa
        incidunt atque sunt rerum quae quidem fugit veniam perspiciatis. Iure,
        nihil? Vel molestiae asperiores soluta totam repudiandae nisi vero,
        dicta repellat exercitationem facilis temporibus, officia itaque ipsum?
        Magnam autem quibusdam esse nisi, cumque quaerat aspernatur accusantium
        labore doloremque voluptates sint maxime odit sit illo, tempora pariatur
        hic dignissimos sunt assumenda ratione? Eum, possimus. Labore inventore
        facere ratione? Explicabo blanditiis necessitatibus odit rerum eveniet
        beatae! Qui sunt beatae at perferendis debitis? Sapiente pariatur
        aliquam tempora, laboriosam hic labore quisquam ipsam. Nesciunt mollitia
        harum nemo dicta at omnis voluptatum! Atque nihil, culpa veniam in dicta
        eius sed ex molestiae, maxime incidunt, deserunt hic accusamus aperiam
        earum? Ducimus, dicta minima nam mollitia enim et molestias est nulla,
        in, amet veritatis! Quos pariatur itaque a, saepe libero eaque tempore.
        In nulla vitae obcaecati eaque nemo autem asperiores, laborum quam harum
        error molestiae aperiam, id ab quasi, debitis unde eius. Doloribus,
        corrupti! Ab adipisci aperiam veritatis deserunt autem fugiat quod
        quaerat ipsam optio, asperiores ipsum provident? Voluptatem excepturi
        labore eaque nisi veritatis dolores quos provident odio dolorum optio,
        recusandae ipsa quasi sequi.
      </p>
    </article>
    <header><h1>HEADING 3</h1></header>
    <article>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat
        ducimus nemo iste, minus debitis architecto, neque assumenda corrupti
        sint rerum recusandae? Voluptas provident obcaecati harum quis enim
        dolor necessitatibus velit? Sint assumenda deleniti, ipsum expedita iste
        explicabo, sed alias accusantium quas ad similique impedit perferendis?
        Possimus molestiae amet a, commodi quidem consequuntur, autem voluptatem
        provident, praesentium dolores dignissimos perferendis quas. Id dicta
        explicabo reprehenderit. Consequuntur magnam nobis, error modi molestias
        nihil assumenda quidem dignissimos reprehenderit aliquid iste ab
        asperiores tempora vero recusandae omnis vitae eaque atque doloribus!
        Itaque, nisi voluptate. Ducimus, nostrum dolore repellat autem magnam ex
        nihil. Repellat perspiciatis nostrum velit. Odio, aperiam quasi. Non eos
        animi, inventore perferendis sint, dolorem tempore porro in adipisci
        dolores aliquam, totam iure? Modi adipisci quia eveniet quos id, hic
        esse. Fuga necessitatibus fugit sit rem enim! Vel, in laudantium.
        Obcaecati maxime delectus praesentium dolor, ea quos harum voluptas
        illum, debitis commodi iusto. Molestiae voluptate, est ipsam, optio
        dolores obcaecati aut modi sapiente laudantium, molestias minus laborum
        ea. Cumque culpa ratione qui nostrum incidunt nemo error aspernatur,
        doloribus dolorum minima reprehenderit obcaecati amet. Quasi repellendus
        exercitationem magnam laudantium pariatur autem nihil deleniti. Esse
        perferendis eligendi vero nam voluptatibus sapiente est ab. Ab numquam
        voluptas velit nobis esse reiciendis omnis adipisci veniam beatae
        corrupti? Nostrum vero minima sit nisi labore obcaecati. Nam odit dolore
        reprehenderit rem labore dolorem laborum excepturi explicabo maxime,
        beatae debitis facilis asperiores quibusdam necessitatibus nostrum
        perspiciatis nihil hic sit illum! Sed ipsum asperiores distinctio
        ratione culpa, et perspiciatis provident, mollitia quam in quis quaerat
        ducimus! Saepe accusamus debitis dolor quo beatae, atque esse doloribus
        perspiciatis culpa et? Quasi, aliquam. Dolores. Quam optio voluptate
        delectus recusandae ipsam dicta iusto debitis. Odio eius cupiditate
        aperiam quod ea asperiores hic. Perspiciatis voluptatum nemo dicta
        inventore, iusto quod sunt reprehenderit aperiam exercitationem,
        officiis quisquam. Neque vitae ipsam ad nihil quisquam quidem excepturi,
        blanditiis dolor tenetur ullam aliquid molestias perferendis odit vero
        placeat iusto minima reprehenderit quod laborum dignissimos explicabo
        minus ut fugit? Officia, omnis. Voluptatibus id accusamus aspernatur
        eaque laudantium sunt quisquam nulla doloribus, suscipit autem, corrupti
        minima consectetur obcaecati? Libero, doloribus illum animi fugiat
        tenetur ipsa id magnam vitae aliquam vel quod repellendus! Ex sunt
        assumenda exercitationem esse ipsum nihil molestiae. Eligendi non at ex
        facere veniam, dolore autem necessitatibus sint nostrum repellat
        voluptatibus fugiat expedita dolor cumque alias, blanditiis, dolorem
        exercitationem pariatur! Eum, impedit, atque, quod placeat vel vero ex
        doloremque harum odit porro reiciendis repellat. Natus, molestiae atque
        similique, cumque, reiciendis quibusdam recusandae totam incidunt quas
        architecto optio vero nulla autem! Ad quibusdam non itaque velit ab
        doloremque ducimus autem iure, nam, sequi at illo commodi, vitae
        excepturi quam molestias officia laboriosam architecto unde amet vero id
        veniam voluptatem doloribus? Soluta. Itaque vitae sequi temporibus
        quisquam dolorum magni perferendis fugit, quaerat sit earum ut, autem,
        pariatur voluptate deleniti maxime quasi odit dolor voluptatem tenetur
        expedita! Voluptatum quos laboriosam fuga beatae sequi. Ipsa molestias
        quaerat hic, soluta quae adipisci maxime exercitationem autem tempore
        labore. Distinctio culpa quis placeat veniam ducimus! Aliquam, cum.
        Deserunt iure consectetur facere reprehenderit ducimus nam quas
        voluptate ad. Nam, saepe quod natus asperiores consequatur iure nobis
        exercitationem recusandae, omnis quas quisquam debitis at sapiente
        cumque! Rerum voluptates maxime corrupti! Voluptatem suscipit quas
        officia molestiae, quasi nostrum voluptate distinctio? Molestias
        veritatis nisi minus voluptatibus incidunt porro culpa eum perferendis
        ipsam voluptates velit qui deserunt, reprehenderit quos tempora sunt
        officiis ex laboriosam optio veniam! Sunt excepturi quidem ad delectus
        tenetur. Ullam enim minima mollitia sequi eaque officiis deleniti est,
        temporibus voluptate fugiat illum magni, quisquam labore aut, quidem
        dicta numquam similique. Expedita aperiam ullam beatae assumenda
        mollitia voluptates, nulla sed. temporibus voluptate fugiat illum magni, quisquam labore aut, quidem
        dicta numquam similique. Expedita aperiam ullam beatae assumenda
        mollitia voluptates, nulla sed.
      </p>
    </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does the header understands when it's content gets completed

Comment: using `postiton: sticky` and   ` top: 0`  whenever header reaches top position it sticks to that position.